# Extracting Almanac using RTKLIB from ublox-M8N

Tags: gps, rtklib, rtkgps+

I am fairly new to this. I have enabled the UBX-RXM-SFRBX command in the M8N and configured the M8N to output .ubx data, after which I recorded a .ubx file using u-center for about 13 minutes(which should be enough to receive an entire message).

Now processing the file using rtkconv, I was able to extract the ephemeris data but I could not extract the almanac data. I opened all of the files generated by rtkconv but none of them contained almanac. Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way to extract almanac using rtklib?

Comment: https://github.com/tomojitakasu/RTKLIB/issues/677